# Why cant I compare between three different values in IF statement? CPP

Tags: c++

Say I have the next code sample:

```
std::string MyString("Michael");
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos);
```

The previous code should give me 1, because the first two returned values from str member function, will be:

> 4294967295

Which is npos value too.
But instead, '0' is printing on the screen.

Another weird thing, is that the next code:

```
std::string MyString("Michael");
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=')) << std::endl; 
std::cout << (str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos) << std::endl;
```

Prints '1' for both of the outputs.

Someone please can explain me why cant I compare 3 values like I did above?

Comment: You *can* do that, it's just that the result of the first comparison will be boolean, so the next `==` will be a boolean comparison, which isn't what you want. `(1 == 2 == false)` will evaluate to `true`, for instance. (It *will* give you a warning with proper warning settings. You've enabled a high warning level, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos); 
// compares the result of a==b with c
```

to

```
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=') &&  str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos); 
// ensures a == b && b == c
```

---

Also, you might pretty much know the answer yourself (just trying to relate things) -

```
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('='))
```

gives you `1` and ofcourse you know `str.npos = 4294967295`

*Simplifying things* -

```
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos)
```

changes to

```
std::cout << (1 == 4294967295)
```

and results in `0`.

***Note*** - Specifically taking the example of `first_of` and `last_of` comparison since the `==` follows *left to right associativity*. Though in your case the result would be same irrespective of that.

Comment: Unless you explain, what the core issue is, and how your proposed answer addresses it, this contribution is not at all helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable the explanation was inlined in the comments. Did I still miss something?

Comment: That's an insanely cryptic way to communicate, and not very comprehensible.

Comment: @IInspectable Okay, updated. Hope that's better now. Do read and let me know if I can amend further.

Answer (score 5):

You can't chain boolean comparisons like that (well you *can*, but it doesn't do what you might think). It would need to be:

```
std::cout << (str.find_first_of('=') == str.npos && str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos);
```

i.e. two comparisons joined by a logical AND.

Comment: This is the right way to do this comparison. Unlike the other answers, it doesn't call `str.find_last_of` twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
(str.find_first_of('=') == str.find_last_of('=') == str.npos)
```

This is basically:

```
(true == str.npos);
```

Which is `false`, thus, giving you `0`.